# How to atone for Fixed costs within MS Project which are based on duration?

Tags: planning, ms-project

I have successfully implemented fixed costs for a few of my tasks, one of them being accommodation cost which is a "one off" cost. However, how do I input fixed costs for tasks which rely on the duration?

For example, one of my tasks involves renting special machinery for 2 days (which is my duration), the cost of renting this equipment is £13,500 per day. So how do I work out the cost, baring in mind that 2 days is the estimated period, in best case scenario the task may take one day,in worst case scenario it may take four days.

So how do I input renting costs? do I just calculate them based on the duration so £13,500 x 2 (days) .. making the fixed cost of £27,000?

Comment: I'm not sure "atone" is the right word, unless there are sins involved; perhaps 'account'?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a material resource with a cost of 13500.  Then assign the material resource at 1/day in the task form.

In the Resource Names column it should look like this:  Auger[1/day]

*Additionally, if there is a fixed cost plus a daily cost ($10,000 + $3,500/day) you can show this by entering $10,000 into the Cost Per Use column of the Resource Sheet and entering $3,500 into the Std. Rate column.